# Gulp jade not including parent directories

Tags: gulp, pug

I've been using grunt for a while and I recently heard about gulp, so I wanted to give it a try and see if I can finally migrate from grunt to gulp.
I created a very simple task that takes my .jade files in two separate directories and compiles them into html.
The problem I'm facing right now is that the parent directory of the .jade files is not getting created in the output directory.
The following is a portion of the gulpfile.js that contains the 'jade' task:

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    jadeOpts = { debug: false };

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src(['partial/**/*.jade','directive/**/*.jade'])
    .pipe($.jade(jadeOpts))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/html')));
});
```

The task runs correctly but, the source .jade files within 'partial' are created on 'dev/html' directory instead of 'dev/html/partial'. The same happens for source .jade files within 'directive' folder.

How can I do to make this task create the source 'partial' .jade files into 'dev/html/partial' folder as well as source 'directive' .jade files into 'dev/html/directive' folder?
Note: I may need to add more 'partial' and 'directive' siblings folders with .jade files as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `.src` part

```
return gulp.src(['partial/**/*.jade','directive/**/*.jade'], {'base' : 'partial/'})
```

so that the `.dest` will consider full path from partial dir while saving the files to dest

Comment: Thanks @entre. The problem is that with 'base' set to `partial/` all files go under `partial` dest directory. But I need the source `partial` go under `partial` and `directive` go under `directive` in the final destination directory.

Comment: then make the base as current `{'base':'.'}`